# Razor Pages model binding [BindProperty] not working correctly - what needs to be done to correct this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have the following code in my .cs file:

```
public class ClientCredentialsModel : PageModel
{
    [BindPropertyAttribute]
    public BusinessUnit businessUnit { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {           
        BusinessUnit businessUnit = new BusinessUnit();

        businessUnit.Name = "Tessla";
    }
}
```

And

```
public class BusinessUnit
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string AddressName { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

..which **should** allow me to access the object's properties in my Razor view as:

```html
<p>Name: @Model.businessUnit.Name</p>
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

[Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMwuC.png)

Comment: What you need to do is decorate with [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] and not [BindPropertyAttribute], since you are doing a GET.